# Compile each cpp file in separate directory

Tags: c++, unix, makefile

The results for this topic strangely all did not work.

Finally I found a variant that is logical for me and works from the same order.

```makefile
CC := g++
CFLAGS := -g -Wall
objects = test helloworld
all: $(objects)

$(objects): %: %.cpp
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $<
```

I have tried a lot and probably fail to fully understand the line `%: %.cpp`.

My interpretation is: I take from every object the dependency which in turn is based on a file which is then traceable to a `.cpp` file.

My theory is test expects `test.o` and then `test.cpp`.

How do I rewrite this to directory?

I have already read some things with wildcards and a pattern replace.

Like

```makefile
SRC_DIR := src
OBJ_DIR := obj
SRC_FILES := $(wildcard $(SRC_DIR)/*.cpp)
OBJ_FILES := $(patsubst $(SRC_DIR)/%.cpp,$(OBJ_DIR)/%.o,$(SRC_FILES))
LDFLAGS := ...
CPPFLAGS := ...
CXXFLAGS := ...

main.exe: $(OBJ_FILES)
   g++ $(LDFLAGS) -o $@ $^

$(OBJ_DIR)/%.o: $(SRC_DIR)/%.cpp
   g++ $(CPPFLAGS) $(CXXFLAGS) -c -o $@ $<
```

But the behavior was not the expected.

When 2 cpp files were in the folder the result was

```
g++ -o helloworld.o helloworld.cpp
g++ -o helloworld.o test.cpp
```

Or vice versa that only the cpp file was always the same.

I have the feeling to miss something extremely.

Update:
The make version is

```
GNU Make 4.3
Built for aarch64-unknown-linux-android
```

The Goal
What I would like to achieve is

- src/

  - Test.cpp
  - Helloworld.cpp
- Obj/

Make :

- Obj/

  - Helloworld.out
  - Test.out

Comment: You should not upload images of text anyway. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Image has been removed.

Comment: Found the language tags for syntax highlighting here: [What is syntax highlighting and how does it work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/184109/565387) ;-)

Comment: *"How do I rewrite this to directory?"* What do you mean? Do you want to automatically find all files in a directory and compile them?

Comment: Could you provide an example of what you try to achieve?

Comment: The current make version is GNU Make 4.3
Built for aarch64-unknown-linux-android

Comment: What I would like to achieve is
src/
Test.cpp
Helloworld.cpp
Obj/

Make :
Obj/
Helloworld.out
Test.out

Comment: Updated my answers to the current request. Thanks @all

Comment: Do you want to produce one executable per project, or one executable per .cpp file? (The latter is **not** a good idea).

Comment: Hey, the last variant is correct. I already thought that it is not a good idea. The whole thing has been an exercise for me to better understand my understanding of makefile thematics. And to be able to use it. Thanks to all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
CXX := g++
CXXFLAGS := -g -Wall
TARGETS=obj/test.out obj/helloworld.out
all:$(TARGETS)

obj/%.out:src/%.cpp
        $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -o $@ $^

clean:
        rm obj/*
```

[image]